# how to make a column for auto serial number to find number of records in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have DataTable, the first column is sl no that I want to make it auto serial number 1,2,3,4...... I want the id column should auto increment.

`{ data: "id", title: "Sl. No." }`

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable({
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // your case first column
                                "className": "text-center",
                            }
                        ],
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "scrollX": true,
                        data: dataSet,
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
                        columns: [
                            { data: "id", title: "Sl. No." },
                            {
                                "data": "updatedDate", title: "Time", render: function (data, type, row) {
                                    return moment(row.updatedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
                                }
                            },
                            { data: "voltage", title: "Voltage" }

                        ],
                        order:[0,"desc"]
                    });
```

Comment: Could you not modify your `dataset` for this before passing to plugin?

Comment: Try: { data: "id", title: "Sl. No.", render:functon(data,type.row){return row.index();} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that add Serial No to datatable using `columnDefs` and its render `option`

```js
var dataSet = [{"name":"Wade Rodriguez","age":21},{"name":"Maxwell Rush","age":31},{"name":"Ruiz Murray","age":40},{"name":"Tanner Crosby","age":37},{"name":"Shelby Douglas","age":25},{"name":"Haney Fulton","age":35}]

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    "columns": [{
        "title": "Sl. No."
      },
      {
        "data": "name",
        "title": "Name"
      },
      {
        "data": "age",
        "title": "Age"
      }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        dataSet[meta.row].id = meta.row + 1; // adds id to dataset
        return meta.row + 1; // adds id to serial no
      },
      "targets": 0
    }],
  });

  console.log(dataSet)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
```